# MySQL Case-insensitive Join

Tags: mysql, join, case-insensitive

I have a table named work that contains registration info for everyone in the enterprise, like this:

Table: work

```
FirstName LastName SponsorshipStatus EnrollmentStatus AdjudicationStatus
--------- -------- ----------------- ---------------- ------------------
JANE      DOE      Complete          Incomplete       Incomplete
JOHN      DOE      Complete          Complete         Incomplete
MONTY     PYTHON   Complete          Complete         Complete
MARY      POPPINS  Complete          Complete         Complete
```

A department manager gives me a list of her employees like the one immediately below and she needs a status update:

Table: employees

```
FirstName LastName
--------- --------
John      Doe
Mary      Poppins
Humpty    Dumpty
```

Knowing that the case of the two tables do not match, I try the  following query:

```
SELECT employees.FirstName, employees.LastName,
    SponsorshipStatus, EnrollmentStatus, AdjudicationStatus
    FROM employees LEFT JOIN work
    ON (UPPER(employees.FirstName) LIKE UPPER(work.FirstName)
    AND UPPER(employees.LastName) LIKE UPPER(work.LastName));
```

...and it produces the following:

Query Result:

```
FirstName LastName SponsorshipStatus EnrollmentStatus AdjudicationStatus
--------- -------- ----------------- ---------------- ------------------
JOHN      DOE      NULL              NULL             NULL
MARY      POPPINS  NULL              NULL             NULL
HUMPTY    DUMPTY   NULL              NULL             NULL
```

This is what I expect to get from the query:

```
FirstName LastName SponsorshipStatus EnrollmentStatus AdjudicationStatus
--------- -------- ----------------- ---------------- ------------------
JOHN      DOE      Complete          Complete         Incomplete
MARY      POPPINS  Complete          Complete         Complete
HUMPTY    DUMPTY   NULL              NULL             NULL
```

What am I doing wrong here? The left join is working correctly, but it is not doing the match and pulling in the relevant data from the work table, as evidenced by all the nulls.

I have already looked at numerous posts here, and none of them seem to clearly help me here.

Comment: What are the data types and collation settings for the `FirstName` and `LastName` columns for both tables? Is there a chance you have trailing spaces in any of the values?

Comment: I don't think there are any extraneous spaces, but not sure how to verify that though. My hunch is that it could be the collation; which collation should I use for this?

Comment: For all four of the name fields, the type declaration is VARCHAR(100), the character set is utf8, and the collation is utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're misusing `LIKE`.  Don't use `LIKE` unless you're pattern-matching.  Change

```
UPPER(employees.FirstName) LIKE UPPER(work.FirstName)
```

to

```
UPPER(employees.FirstName) = UPPER(work.FirstName)
```

Do the same with the lastname, too.

Comment: Actually you can avoid problems like this in the first place, by using numerical keys (auto-increment values) to reference records in other tables.

Comment: Andy, I tried the equal signs instead of LIKE, and it gave me the same results. There is something else wrong here.

Comment: That could be.  Still, make sure you use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: Andy,  after reading your original response, I immediately went back to my script, changed 'LIKE' to '=', reran it and got the same results. This tells me that there is something else amiss here. Could it possibly an encoding issue caused by using the incorrect encoding while importing the data?

Comment: I understand that the `=` instead of `LIKE` is not solving your problem.  All I am saying is that it is incorrect to use `LIKE` in this case, whether it's the core of your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 5.0.3, when you retrieve values for a `VARCHAR` column, any trailing spaces are included. This can be a concern because when using `=` comparison, trailing spaces are ignored, whereas with `LIKE` trailing spaces are considered.

```
SELECT 'foo' = 'foo ';
// Returns true

SELECT 'foo' LIKE 'foo ';
// Returns false
```

So, be sure to use the appropriate operator.

Since the collation on the column is `CASE INSENSITIVE`, you don't need the `UPPER()` function. In fact, dropping `UPPER` will allow MySQL to utilize an index on the column (using a function on a column generally negates the use of an index).

```
 // With case insensitive collation
 SELECT 'FOO' = 'foo';
 // Returns true

 // LIKE will work the same
 SELECT 'FOO' LIKE 'foo';
 // Returns true
```

Since `=` and `LIKE` return the same results for you, however, I don't know what the issue is.

You should also specify the table name for all columns in a join to avoid any chance of ambiguous columns (if you were to add similar columns to the other table in the future), and for readability:

```
SELECT employees.FirstName, employees.LastName,
    work.SponsorshipStatus, work.EnrollmentStatus, work.AdjudicationStatus
    FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN work
    ON employees.FirstName = work.FirstName
    AND employees.LastName = work.LastName;
```

However, if the columns were ambiguous, you should get an error.